# Remove Entries from Chrome's preloaded HSTS list

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any way to remove entries from Chrome's preloaded HSTS list?

For development reasons I need to route a webpage through [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), but that webpage loads jQuery from ajax.googleapis.com - which is on Chrome's [preloaded HSTS list](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json). This results in an error while loading jQuery, so the page stops working.

I know that I can [remove entries from the dynamically created HSTS list](https://superuser.com/questions/480200/how-to-disable-ssl-for-some-websites-in-chrome/481277#481277) via *chrome://net-internals/#hsts* - but not entries that come with the browser.

Is there any way to tell Chrome that I know what I'm doing?

Answer (score -1):

BIG WORKAROUND:

1) Create a web site where you have control... eg: xyz.mydomain.com

2) Put the resource that you want on that site

3) Snif and replace ajax.googleapis.com to

Comment: replace ajax.googleapis.com with what?

Comment: Your own copy of the file, I guess. That's not a solution to "remove entries from preloaded HSTS list", though.